# Filter a DataTable using input texts client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, datatable

I have a HTML page with some script inside the head, and I have a DataTable with the ID=example, and a button id="btnFilter" which is supposed to filter the data in the DataTable based on what the user typed inside others "input texts tags". 
I've tried a lot of variations I found on internet but I'm not being able to do anything that can do what I want.

Here is my HTML where I have the input and label tags, where the user will type the text he wants to filter:

```
<table id="filterLog" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <h4>Table</h4>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="input-group">From:</label></td>
                    <td><label class="input-group">To:</label></td>
                    <td><label class="input-group">Created:</label></td>
                    <td><label class="input-group">Comp:</label></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tr id="linhasFiltro">
                <td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="date1" /></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="date2" /></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="creator" maxlength="15" /></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="cLog" maxlength="10"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><label class="input-group">Type:</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <select id="tipoLog" class="form-control">
                        <option>Error</option>
                        <option>Test</option>
                        <option>Info</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Filter" id="btnFilter" class="btn btn-primary" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Exportar" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="border:0px;">
                <td colspan="6" id="consiError"  ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And ALL I WANT is, when the user type inside the input id="cLog" and click on btnFiltrar, the DataTable must show all rows that has the same text in the column equivalent.

Thx guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to be more specific in yours next questions, show us what u already tryied.
People should not write your solution, you should write what you have tried and what is your problem and people will help you.

Take a look at DataTables plugin:
https://datatables.net/

Working example with DataTables:
https://jsfiddle.net/kt0yotsn/

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:

//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

The following CSS library files are loaded for use in this example to provide the styling of the table:

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Answer (score -2):

I know it has been a while since I posted here, but, I managed to do it just like this.

```js
function Filter($("#cLog").val()) {
            if (!($("#cLog").val() == "-Default-")) {
                tabelaProjetos.columns().every(function () {
                    var columnRelated = dataTableName.column(1);
                    if (columnRelated.search() !== $("#cLog").val()) {
                        columnRelated
                            .search($("#cLog").val());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

That code above filters an specific column based on an specific `'input'` inside the form. So, I did others Filter functions to filter others inputs separatedly, and managed to call all these functions in a `btnClick event`, and BEHOLD, the DataTable was filtered.

Hope I can help someone, and HOPE EVEN MORE that my english is at least readable.

Thxx